# Play-framework 2 Validation

Tags: java, playframework-2.3

so i did a one line tweak on the play-computer-database-java activator template

the models:

**Computer:**

```
package models;

import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

import play.db.ebean.*;
import play.data.format.*;
import play.data.validation.*;

import com.avaje.ebean.*;

/**
 * Computer entity managed by Ebean
 */
@Entity
public class Computer extends Model {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String name;

    @Formats.DateTime(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    public Date introduced;

    @Formats.DateTime(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    public Date discontinued;

    @Constraints.Required
    @ManyToOne
    public Company company;

    /**
     * Generic query helper for entity Computer with id Long
     */
    public static Finder<Long, Computer> find = new Finder<Long, Computer>(Long.class, Computer.class);

    /**
     * Return a page of computer
     *
     * @param page     Page to display
     * @param pageSize Number of computers per page
     * @param sortBy   Computer property used for sorting
     * @param order    Sort order (either or asc or desc)
     * @param filter   Filter applied on the name column
     */
    public static Page<Computer> page(int page, int pageSize, String sortBy, String order, String filter) {
        return find.where()
                .ilike("name", "%" + filter + "%")
                .orderBy(sortBy + " " + order)
                .fetch("company")
                .findPagingList(pageSize)
                .setFetchAhead(false)
                .getPage(page);
    }
}
```

**Company:**

```
package models;

import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

import play.db.ebean.*;
import play.data.validation.*;


/**
 * Company entity managed by Ebean
 */
@Entity
public class Company extends Model {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String name;

    /**
     * Generic query helper for entity Company with id Long
     */
    public static Model.Finder<Long, Company> find = new Model.Finder<Long, Company>(Long.class, Company.class);

    public static Map<String, String> options() {
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> options = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        for (Company c : Company.find.orderBy("name").findList()) {
            options.put(c.id.toString(), c.name);
        }
        return options;
    }
}
```

and the controller

```
package controllers;

import play.mvc.*;
import play.data.*;

import static play.data.Form.*;

import views.html.*;

import models.*;

/**
 * Manage a database of computers
 */
public class Application extends Controller {

    /**
     * This result directly redirect to application home.
     */
    public static Result GO_HOME = redirect(
            routes.Application.list(0, "name", "asc", "")
    );

    /**
     * Handle default path requests, redirect to computers list
     */
    public static Result index() {
        return GO_HOME;
    }

    /**
     * Display the paginated list of computers.
     *
     * @param page   Current page number (starts from 0)
     * @param sortBy Column to be sorted
     * @param order  Sort order (either asc or desc)
     * @param filter Filter applied on computer names
     */
    public static Result list(int page, String sortBy, String order, String filter) {
        return ok(
                list.render(
                        Computer.page(page, 10, sortBy, order, filter),
                        sortBy, order, filter
                )
        );
    }

    /**
     * Display the 'edit form' of a existing Computer.
     *
     * @param id Id of the computer to edit
     */
    public static Result edit(Long id) {
        Form<Computer> computerForm = form(Computer.class).fill(
                Computer.find.byId(id)
        );
        return ok(
                editForm.render(id, computerForm)
        );
    }

    /**
     * Handle the 'edit form' submission
     *
     * @param id Id of the computer to edit
     */
    public static Result update(Long id) {
        Form<Computer> computerForm = form(Computer.class).bindFromRequest();
        if (computerForm.hasErrors()) {
            return badRequest(editForm.render(id, computerForm));
        }
        computerForm.get().update(id);
        flash("success", "Computer " + computerForm.get().name + " has been updated");
        return GO_HOME;
    }

    /**
     * Display the 'new computer form'.
     */
    public static Result create() {
        Form<Computer> computerForm = form(Computer.class);
        return ok(
                createForm.render(computerForm)
        );
    }

    /**
     * Handle the 'new computer form' submission
     */
    public static Result save() {
        Form<Computer> computerForm = form(Computer.class).bindFromRequest();
        if (computerForm.hasErrors()) {
            return badRequest(createForm.render(computerForm));
        }
        computerForm.get().save();
        flash("success", "Computer " + computerForm.get().name + " has been created");
        return GO_HOME;
    }

    /**
     * Handle computer deletion
     */
    public static Result delete(Long id) {
        Computer.find.ref(id).delete();
        flash("success", "Computer has been deleted");
        return GO_HOME;
    }
}
```

the only addition was to add a @Constraints.Required to the company field of the Computer model, so that a computer should not be added without it being attached to a company, however the field is not being validated in the form, a computer still gets added without it having a company. is this a bug or am i doing something wrongly

Comment: It's correct, have you try to clean the project?

Comment: yes still the same result